# Systemd run script after GUI is ready?

Tags: systemd, startup

I'm running raspbian on pi. I've created a systemd script which runs a node.js app on startup.

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/pi/pop_machine && /usr/bin/npm start
```

**Systemd Service:**

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/pop_machine/start_pop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The script works if I run it manually but not on startup. I'm wondering if it's because it tries to run before its dependencies.

I've seen people require networking before running by adding a line to `[install]` is there something similar where I can wait until everything to run a GUI application is ready?

*I assume I just need x-window?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved by adding these to service:

```
[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: Probably you also enable and start it. [You didn't use .timer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1083647/349837)?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and that `graphical.target` works great. I also have the `Environment="DISPLAY=:0"`. However, the `.Xauthority`, I did not try with that one. I don't think it's saved at that location anymore anyway.

Comment: @PabloA Why would you start a GUI app. on a timer?!

Comment: This was long time ago, I'm not sure what I meant with the timer. BTW, could be useful on some cases. Also, you probably enabled the service also, you could mention that (obvious, though). Did you mean you didn't try _without_ `.Xauthority`? If it's necessary, could be useful its content.