# Decision making in selection of appropriate target for Systemd user service that requires desktop environment to be loaded

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, firefox, gui

This question is not duplicate of [startup - Systemd run script after GUI is ready? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388837/systemd-run-script-after-gui-is-ready) as this is concerned with the informed selection of the right target, while the Url is concerned with just the end result. This questions aims to highlight decision making in selection of the target.

#### Past Experience of running GUI application

I was successful in running these GUI services without having to define Environment variables  variable in Ubuntu 20.04. I am facing problem in Linux Mint 20.3. I think the reason is non availability of  suitable targets. For example the following worked successfully in Ubuntu

```
[Unit]
Description=Browser Service

[Service]
ExecStart=firefox
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=BrowserService
# Refer: [Adjust or silence a systemd service’s logging levels](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/systemd-log-levels.html)
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target # Ubuntu
```

---

- System Info: Kernel: 5.4.0-94-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.2.7 Distro: Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
- Since, User units can not reference or depend on system units or units of other users. I listed all user target unit files

```
$ find   /usr/lib/systemd/user   ~/.local/share/systemd/user   /etc/systemd/user   ~/.config/systemd/user   -type f -name '*.target' | sort
find: ‘/home/nikhil/.local/share/systemd/user’: No such file or directory
/home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/default.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/basic.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/bluetooth.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/exit.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-failed.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-initialized.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-manager.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-pre.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-shutdown.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session@.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-wayland.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-wayland@.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-x11-services.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-x11.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-session-x11@.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session-pre.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-a11y-settings.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-color.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-datetime.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-housekeeping.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-keyboard.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-media-keys.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-power.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-print-notifications.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-rfkill.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-screensaver-proxy.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-sharing.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-smartcard.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-sound.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-usb-protection.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-wacom.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-wwan.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gsd-xsettings.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/paths.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/printer.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/shutdown.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/smartcard.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/sockets.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/sound.target
/usr/lib/systemd/user/timers.target
```

- Also the active unit files are as follows:

```
$ systemctl --user list-units --type target --state active
  UNIT           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION     
  basic.target   loaded active active Basic System    
  default.target loaded active active Main User Target
  paths.target   loaded active active Paths           
  sockets.target loaded active active Sockets         
  timers.target  loaded active active Timers          

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

5 loaded units listed.
```

### Task

I want to start firefox using Systemd user service unit. I am assuming that I can use the target `/usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session.target`.

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/graphical-session.target

[Unit]
Description=Current graphical user session
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=basic.target
RefuseManualStart=yes
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
```

But, I am not sure about whether this is the right target or not.

```
$ cat /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/Browser.service

[Unit]
Description=Browser Service

[Service]
ExecStart=firefox
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=BrowserService
# Refer: [Adjust or silence a systemd service’s logging levels](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/systemd-log-levels.html)
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

I enabled the service file and reloaded the systemd user demon

```
$ ls -lA /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/graphical-session.target.wants/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nikhil 49 Jan 14 13:30 Browser.service -> /home/nikhil/.config/systemd/user/Browser.service

$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

### Issue

1. But after login out and relogging in, the firefox is not starting. Any suggestions?
2. Did I choose the right target? If not, what should I choose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Systemd run script after GUI is ready?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388837/systemd-run-script-after-gui-is-ready)

Comment: It's a bit tricky, but I think you need to set `XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY` as `ENVIRONMENT=`. Helped me with a similar problem for a service to be started after GUI is up. Also a re-login was not sufficient, I needed to reboot.

Comment: @FelixJN The question answers without any explanation, so I am not sure if it works but I will try what is suggested and I will let you know. I was successful in running these GUI services without having to define these variable in Ubuntu 20.04. I am facing problem in Linux Mint 20.3. I think the reason is non availability of  suitable targets.

Comment: @Porcupine were you able to solve it? I'm dealing with similar problem for a few days and it drives me crazy